# Extracting Excel formulas from cells using vb.net as strings

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

How hard can this be...or so I thought. What I'm trying to do is extract values, colors, comments, and any formulas for a range of cells in a given worksheet. The ultimate goal is convert a spreadsheet someone has been using as a database into Access tables.

`worksheet.Cells(row,column).Value` 'extract value WORKS
`worksheet.Cells(row,column).Font.ColorIndex` 'extract color index WORKS
`worksheet.Cells(row,column).Comment.Text` 'extract comment WORKS
`worksheet.Cells(row,column).Formula` 'extract formula DOES NOT WORK

The return value for `.Formula` is same as `.Value`. That's not what I need. I'm looking for a textual representation of the formula (to extract rate information embedded within the formula).

Comment: Works for me in VBA. Is there something you aren't telling us? What's in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Agreeing with David.  Are you certain the cell has a formula?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David for testing the code in VBA. I should have done that before posting the question.

Update: I tested the code using VBA. It works. So I went back to my VB.Net code and found the problem. I think there's a bug in VB.Net properties and here's why.

I have a class ExcelSheet that holds a reference to Excel.Worksheet. It implements an indexer [row,colum] that returns another class ExcelRange which holds a reference to Excel.Range. The bug I noticed is that the 1st MsgBox displays formulas as their string representation while the 2nd MsgBox displays evaluated data. My quick fix was to capture the formula in the constructor.

```
Private myCell As Excel.Range  
Private myFormula As String  

Friend Sub New(ByRef cell As Excel.Range)  
myCell = cell  
MsgBox(myCell.Formula,,"Constructor") 'Displays formula as string  
myFormula = myCell.Formula 'Saving formula as string  
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Formula() As String  
  Get  
    MsgBox(myCell.Formula,,"Property") 'Displays evaluated data  
    Return myFormula 'Return formula saved as string in constructor  
  End Get  
End Property
```

This fixed my problem but I'm curious as why VB.Net behaves this way.